# Determine The Metric In a Space $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\lambda)$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces, lebesgue-measure

Determine the metric $d(A,B)$ when $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\lambda)$ when $B=[-1,1]$ and $A=\left \{ x|\: x^2\leq x+1 \right \}$.

By the definitions it is known that the metric maps to a real number greater than or equal to $0$ (so a real valued non-negative function), it is symmetrical and the triangle inequality. Graphing the sets I get that A is contained between $\left [ 1/2(1-\sqrt{5}),1/2(1+\sqrt{5})  \right ]$ but obviously that is not considering $B$. How do I determine the metric from the given information and the definitions? i.e what is really meant by 'determine'?

Comment: What is your definition of $d(A,B)$?

Comment: @grover Presumably the metric induced by the measure in the standard way? But OP should indeed specify.

Comment: Hint: Compute $A$ first in a standard form. It must be a (union of) interval(s).

Answer (score 1):

You claim that $A= [\frac12(1-\sqrt{5}), \frac12(1+\sqrt{5})]$. Looks plausible.

By **definition** $d(A,B)=\lambda(A \Delta B)$. So compute $A \Delta B$, and then find its Lebesgue measure.

Voilà, you've determined/computed $d(A,B)$...